# Develop a web application in java EE using only a servlet container?

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, application-server, web-container

I do some research about deploying web application in *Javaee*, and i found that an application server compatible Java EE is a web container plus **EJB container**. Also that Tomcat is just a **web container** not an application server.

In my case, i have to develop a web application, and i'm not in need of EJB components, so can i simply use a web container without an application server ? Or, i need also a server application?

Comment: Short version: Yes, Tomcat (or Jetty) will be sufficient.

Comment: And i will have the 3 layers in my application? I mean: business layer, web layer and  Enterprise Information System layer?

Comment: You can, but you don't have to. These terms aren't necessarily bound to JavaEE

Comment: So in Java EE, what is the architecture of an application?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Tomcat will be sufficient as long as you restrict your use of Java EE to the following APIs:

1. Servlet
2. JSP
3. EL
4. WebSocket

If you need other APIs, you can either package together with your application, or use something like [Apache TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html), which is a web-profile-certified Java EE server with out-of-the-box support for a handful of other useful APIs without the bulk of something like WebLogic, etc.